# webapp keep localstorage when upgrade/reintall apk

Tags: local-storage

I store some data in localstorage when I develop a android webapp, but I found that when I re-install the apk built after I had revised the html/css/javascript file content in asset directory. the data in localstorage was empty. How to avoid this status, or any other solution should I use?

Comment: I found that when I upload the html/css/js zip package to phonegap, PG can build it to an apk, and this version will keep localstorage when I reinstall the apk. But not the eclipse build one.

Comment: WebView wv = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
  WebSettings settings = wv.getSettings();
  settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
  settings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
  settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true); // Enable localStorage
  settings.setDatabasePath(wv.getContext().getFilesDir().getPath() + wv.getContext().getPackageName() + "/databases/");

Comment: above code resolve this problem